# is there a collection mapping jquery function where end method works against base query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following query:

```
$(some_selector_here).find("ul li.active a span")
```

I need a function which loops through the collection and inside of a looping function it would have the full stack of base elements. I tried `map` and `each` but they have `DOM` elements passed inside, instead of `jQuery` element. The question is, is there a ready function for this or any ways to implement it by hand?
Example:

```
$(some_selector_here).find("ul li.active a span").each(function () {
  // here I want to get this $(some_selector_here)
  var parentElement = $(this).end();
})
```

Comment: You mean `$(this).parent()` ? what element are you trying to track? `A/LI/UL`?

Comment: @LShetty almost, I mean base selector which is a `n` level parent for inner element, but `parent()` would return upper node element. I need that parent element, which is written in the code by `some_selector_here`

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you're not "forced" to use `this` in your `.each`:

```
var base = $(some_selector_here);
base.find("ul li.active a span").each(function () {
  // now you can access base, which is == $(some_selector_here)
  var parentElement = $(this).end();
})
```

Comment: I am getting an empty array

Comment: It is the same, no changes. Which is the version of your `jQuery`, if it is working on you?

Comment: I haven't tested anything - I don't even think I'm understanding your question correctly. What do you expect the "full stack of base elements" to be?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(some_selector_here).find("ul li.active a span").each(function () {
    var selector = $(some_selector_here);   // here you have
    var parentElement = $(this).end();
})
```

**updated**
To get the parent of specific element

Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(some_selector_here).find("ul li.active a span").each(function () {
    var parent = $(this).cloest('some_selector_here');   // here you have
    var parentElement = $(this).end();
})
```

or
Use [`parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$(some_selector_here).find("ul li.active a span").each(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parents('some_selector_here');   // here you have
    var parentElement = $(this).end();
})
```

Comment: In this case I have selector of all elements. I want to have parent element by selector for the specific element inside the loop.